# Delete containing row of clicked td JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to manage my HTML table, add and delete rows. What I am trying to do, is to delete an entire row by clicking on an element (). 
Yet, when an element is clicked the parents of all  tags are being deleted. is there anyway to specify the clicked element and delete only the row containing that element specifically for this type of adjustable tables where rows can be added and deleted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
    $("td").parentsUntil("table").remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body> 
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td><td>test4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test5</td><td>test6</td><td>test7</td><td>test8</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to traverse to closest tr element in click handler and then remove it. For this you need the jquery object of clicked element along with `.closest()` or `.parent()` selector:

```
$("td").click(function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

**Working Snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
      $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body> 
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td><td>test4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test5</td><td>test6</td><td>test7</td><td>test8</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you so much.

Comment: @SaharAlsadah: glad it helps :)

Comment: It does for the fixed size table. But when I add and (add row) button, it does not do the job for the additional rows. Any Idea why?

Comment: You need to use event delegation for that.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("table").append("<tr><td>test5</td><td>test6</td><td>test7</td><td>test8</td></tr>");
    });
    $("td").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
</script>

Comment: </head>

<body> 
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td><td>test4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test5</td><td>test6</td><td>test7</td><td>test8</td></tr>
    
  </table>
   <button>Add</button>
</body>

</html>

Comment: what's an event delegation ?

Comment: `$("body").on('click','td',function(){ $(this).closest("tr").remove(); }); `

Comment: Ok. Will try that out

Comment: can I use it with a class instead of td ?

Comment: @SaharAlsadah: yes you can. put the class that td elements have.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @SaharAlsadah: great :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Just select the parent of that `<td>` element; it would be `<tr>`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("td").click(function(){
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body> 
  <table border="1">
    <tr><td>test1</td><td>test2</td><td>test3</td><td>test4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test5</td><td>test6</td><td>test7</td><td>test8</td></tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot